# Convert json string as javascript variable or object

Tags: javascript, json, string, variables

Following is the part of the json response from the server.

```
exam_section_id: ["SCjnqwh4vcng", "SCasqdesml6k"]

SCjnqwh4vcng : Object { n_sec_id="SCasqdesml6k", c_section_max_time="7", c_section_time_mode="limited", more...}
```

I'll get the list of section ids (`exam_section_id`) from the json and respective sections objects (`SCjnqwh4vcng :` ).
I have to loop through the list of section ids and parse the section objects dynamically.

If i use `response.exam_section_id[0]` it is giving the section id string `"SCjnqwh4vcng"`.
How can  i get the section object.

I tried using getJSONobj(response.exam_section_id[0]). not worked.

I have to convert the js string as variable which is from json.

i seen converting js srting to varaible using window['variable_name']. But it won't work with json. It work with window variables only.

Can any one help on this

Comment: is the word Object their in the response?

Comment: Yeah... that's not a JSON response.

Comment: I copied the part of the json data from firebug tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the id of the section is used as a key in the JSON object, you need to refer to it dynamically like this:

```
response[response.exam_section_id[0]]
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. I tried the same before but it not worked. may be i used in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the value of the "JSON" object like that from Firebug, then it's no longer JSON but a JavaScript object in a variable. To access the object you need it's then

```
variablename[response.exam_section_id[0]]
```

If that doesn't work, you need to show us:

- The complete(!) relevant code (including `getJSONobj` what ever that is.
- The content of the ajax result in the network tab of Firebug  (not the content of the variable!)